# Load a library in a helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

In a library/controller, another library can be loaded by using

```
$this->CI->load->library("LIB_NAME");
```

inside the constructor of that particular library/controller. However, a helper doesn't have a class and thus, a constructor.
So, how can I load a library in a helper?

Also, provide any alternative, if any, for the same.

Comment: what was the answer? Check one of the below as the right answer, or answer yourself so people with the same problem can find it here.

Comment: @NathanQ, Thanks for your useful tip. I've marked the suitable answer to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load a library inside a helper you need to get a CI instance:

File helper.php:

```
if(!function_exists('my_helper_function')
{
  function my_helper_function($params)
  {
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('library_name');
    $CI->library_name->do_something();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; works fine.
Although, the third line in your code must be 
$CI->library_name->do_something();

Comment: Also, @Ankesh, please don't forget to upvote all useful answers and/or mark the correct one as "accepted" (with the tick mark you see under the vote count). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the last comment too. Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

In your helper, you could just do:

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->library("LIB_NAME");
```

Have a look in the [Codeigniter userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Comment: Thanks; works fine. I was instead trying with 
$this->CI = &get_instance();
$this->CI->load->library("LIB_NAME");

Answer (score 0):

Helpers are just bunch of php functions stored in regular .php files. to load your own, do the following:

1. Save the .php file in `application/helpers` directory
2. Load the using the following function:

`$this->load->helper('name');`

where **name** is the file name of the helper, without the .php file extension.Once you've loaded the php File, you'll call it the way you would a standard PHP function.

Comment: What I actually mean, is to include a library inside this helper.